# MySQL - Delimiter error

Tags: mysql, delimiter

I have the following procedure

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE yesterday()
BEGIN
SELECT CURDATE()-INTERVAL 1 DAY;
END $$
DELIMITER;
```

The procedure compiles with error though `CALL yesterday();`  generates correct output.

the error is :

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DELIMITER' at line 1
```

I cant find whats going wrong.
Please help!

Comment: how are you creating the procedure ? using mysql command line or some service side language ?

Comment: Found the problem.Anyways I was directly trying this on MySQl console.

Comment: If the answer is not listed below -create a new answer and accept it - might help others ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a space after the word `DELIMITER`

```
DELIMITER $$ 

CREATE PROCEDURE yesterday() 
BEGIN 
SELECT CURDATE()-INTERVAL 1 DAY; 
END $$ 
DELIMITER ;
```